# Extracting numbers from a string but not the year part in RegEx

Tags: regex

I  have string the below I want to extract the numbers but not the date -ie 2/15/2020 or 2/19/2020.

Please note the numbers could be seperated by , or \r\n or blank or any other characters.

```
test_string = 'Get me data for the below \r\n11011\r\n11045\r\n11051\r\n11063\r\n11079 12462,13003  starting 2/15/2020 to 2/19/2020'
```

Comand I used:

```
re.compile("(\d+)[\r\n*|\n\r*|\,.|\r*|\s*]").findall(s)
```

Expected out put :

```
['11011', '11045', '11051', '11063', '11079', '12462', '13003']
```

but I get the below

```
['11011', '11045', '11051', '11063', '11079', '12462', '13003', '2020']
```

Comment: `[\r\n*|\n\r*|\,.|\r*|\s*]` is a wrong pattern, you must have meant to use `(?:...)`

Comment: Yes. Initialy I just used re.compile("(\d+)").findall(s), but I got all numbers including months and date.  Then I used to start ?: but this time I got the above with year.

Comment: Ok, a quick solution is to match what you do not need and match and capture what you need. `[x for x in re.findall(r'(?<!\d)\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2}(?:\d{2})?(?!\d)|(\d+)', text) if x]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code**

```
import re
test = 'Get me data for the below \r\n11011\r\n11045\r\n11051\r\n11063\r\n11079 12462,13003  starting 2/15/2020 to 2/19/2020'
re.findall('(\d{5,})'), test)
```

output:

```
['11011', '11045', '11051', '11063', '11079', '12462', '13003']
```

**Explaination**

it matches every digit with lenght >= 5

Comment: Can you tell me what if the digit length is 4, some time I may have any length numbers

Comment: if you set lenght to 4 it will catch also 2020

Comment: now i work to find a more global variant, this was very specific to your case